# Monopoly: Board creation

Tags: php, html, css

After initially [struggling with the board size](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40468/monopoly-creating-a-monopoly-board), I have now decided the dimension. Please review my code. In the code I am generating HTML code using PHP and MySql. I have not added the database, please let me know how to add it in my question.

The key functionality is `drawBoard()` it has 3 parameters,

- `1` is to determine whether I will increment or decrease,
- `2` determines where to start from
- `3` determines where to end at

Please let me know if further clarification is required. I have also omitted the generated HTML instead here is [a picture](http://snag.gy/tMmkq.jpg) of what the output looks like. Let me know if generated HTML is needed?

I am looking for ways to improve the code and would like to know whether a more quicker loading time can be achieved. Any general suggestions are also welcome.

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
    include 'header.php';
    include 'functions.php';
?>
<div class="board">
    <div class="row" id="top-row">
        <?php drawBoard(1, 0, 11); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="center-row">
        <div class="left-column">
              <?php drawBoard(-1, 39, 30); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="center-colum">
        </div>
        <div class="right-column">
            <?php drawBoard(1, 11, 20); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="bottom-row">
        <?php drawBoard(-1, 30, 19); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php 

function drawBoard($diff = "", $start = "", $stop =""){

  include 'dbconnect.php';

  for ($i = $start; $i != $stop; $i += $diff){

    $criteria = "pos" . $i;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM positions WHERE position = '$criteria'")
    or die("Could not select examples");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $posid = $row[0];
        $title = $row[1];
        $set = $row[2];
        $withIcon = $row[3];

        if ($withIcon == 0) { ?>

          <div class="position">

                <div class="title">

                  <span class="<?php echo $set ?>"> <?php echo $title ?></span>

                </div>

                <div class="runway" id="<?php echo "runway" .$posid ?>">

                  <span class="piece-1" id="<?php echo "piece1"  .$posid ?>"></span>
                  <span class="piece-2" id="<?php echo "piece2" .$posid ?>"></span>

                </div>

                <div class="price">

                  <span class="price" id="<?php echo "price" .$posid ?>"></span> 

                </div>

          </div>
  <?php 
        }
        else { ?>

                <div class="position">

                  <div class="runway" id="<?php echo "runway" .$posid ?>">

                    <span class="piece-1" id="<?php echo "piece1"  .$posid ?>"></span>
                    <span class="piece-2" id="<?php echo "piece2" .$posid ?>"></span>

                  </div>

                  <div class="positionbody">

                    <span class="<?php echo $set ?>"></span> 

                  </div>

                </div>
<?php
        }; 
    }
  }
}  
?>
```

**CSS**

```
span{
    display: block;
    font: bold 10px "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
/***********************
    Board Structure
************************/
.board {
    background: #EBEBE0;
    width: 845px;
}
.row{
    background: #fff;  
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.left-column{
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
}
.center-column{
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
}
.right-column{
    float: right;
    width: 75px;
}
/************************
    Board Positions
************************/
.position {
    border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    float: left;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
    width: 73px;
}
div .position:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
/************************
    Positions Title
************************/
.title span{
    line-height: 14px;
}
.brown, .blue, .pink, .orange, .red, .yellow, .green, .navy{
    height: 14px;   
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.brown{
    background: #AA6220;
}
.blue{
    background: #7AC0F6;
}
.pink{
    background: #FF356E;
}
.orange{
    background: #FF7A00;
}
.red{
    background: #C40101;
}
.yellow{
    background: #FFFF00;
    color: black;
}
.green{
    background: #0B860B;
}
.navy{
    background: #001791;
}

/************************
    Positions Runway
************************/
.runway{
    height: 12px;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.piece-1{
    background-image:url('../img/piece2.png');
    float: left;
    height:12px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    width: 12px;
}
/***********************
    Positions Body
************************/
.positionbody{
    height:32px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.go, .chest, .airport, .taxes, .chance, .jailhouse{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.go{
    background-image:url('../img/go.png');
}
.chest{
    background-image:url('../img/chest.png');
}
.taxes{
    background-image:url('../img/taxes.png');
}
.airport{
    background-image:url('../img/plane.ico');
    z-index: -1;
}
.airport-title{
    height: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top:-8px;
}
.chance{
    background-image:url('../img/chance.png');
}
.jailhouse{
    background-image:url('../img/jail.png');
}
/***********************
    Positions Price
************************/
.price{
    height: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

**Post Edit**

```
for ($i = $start; $i != $stop; $i += $diff){
```

This for loop gets its variables from the function parameters. I want to reduce my parameters to just 2 instead of 3. Parameter `$diff` tells the `for loop` to either `i++` or `i--`. The only other way I can think of achieving this with just 2 parameters is using an if statement like `if $start > $stop then $i--` but that would mean additional lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

When mixing if statements and HTML I and others often use the [alternative syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), which makes it easier to spot what's being closed even though the brackets might have a great deal of distance between them:

```
if( condition ): ?>
    HTML
<?php endif;
```

I like the idea of using semantic variables instead of `$row[index]` but I think there are more elegant ways of making the assignments. For example by using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` you might get a semantic associative array that you could use and skip the extra assignments, or you could use

```
list($posid, $title, ...,...) = $row;
```

To fix the problem that you mention in your edit you could do for example:

```
for ($i = min($start,$stop); $i != max($start, $stop); $i += 1){
```

If it doesn't matter in which order you loop through the elements. In this case I guess it does, so you would have to get the sign of the difference ($stop-$start):

```
$diff = ($stop > $start) ? 1 : -1;
```

Finally I think that the default values of `drawBoard` should be numeric.

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: I don't know PHP. Also I haven't tested this.

Running on the assumption that position is a number or number-like value I figure you could do something like:

```
function drawBoard($order = "DESC", $start = "", $stop =""){

    include 'dbconnect.php';


     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM positions WHERE REPLACE(position, 'pos', '') BETWEEN '$start' AND '$stop' ORDER BY position $order")
    or die("Could not select examples");


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

This is one call to SQL. Replace `$diff` with order *(holding either `ASC` or `DESC`). no `for` loop.

**BUT** the values in `position` would work better without the prefix "pos" and as a numeric value.